# Getting 403 forbidden Error when running Docker from VS

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker

I have an ASP.Net Web Application and I have turned on Docker Support for it.
So when I use Docker File as below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

It all works fine and WebSite opens locally and I can even hit breakpoint in VS.

And when I use

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2 
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

I am getting Exception as:

> Unable to start debugging on Web Server 403 Forbidden

What's wrong when I use `FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2`

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using .net core?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' What does it matter? People have legacy apps that run on .NET framework and it's perfectly legitimate to want to Dockerize them.

Comment: Totally agree with you